# Chrome OSX color broken

Tags: macos, google-chrome, srgb, color-management

Every color on the web (as far as I can tell) is displayed inconsistently in Google Chrome 43.0 on a MacBook Air running OSX 10.3 with an unmodified LCD color profile. Before attempting it yourself, [Watch this short YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XX90LTdKwlY) demonstrating the problem: When switching between desktops or accessing context menus, the color becomes saturated like those seen in Safari. On scroll, the colors revert to the more dull versions normally seen in Chrome.

Here's a question: does anyone know how to prevent this inconsistency?
Embedding color profiles seems to be far from enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental color management problems between Chrome and OSX have resolved themselves within the past six months as of Chrome 47 on OSX 10 El Capitan. Using the most recent updates, the color management inconsistencies with Chrome 43 on OSX 11 Yosemite shown in [the video posted above](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XX90LTdKwlY) thankfully no longer persist.